# How to fix "Property 'should' does not exist on type 'string'" error in a TypeScript project using mocha?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

In a NodeJS project I'm working on that uses TypeScript, there are some .ts files that have tests in them that use mocha. I have ported a file of tests over from javascript to TypeScript, and I'm getting these errors on a few lines:

```
Property 'should' does not exist on type 'number'.
Property 'should' does not exist on type 'boolean'.
Property 'should' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

I've seen this before in some other repos, and I remember fixing it, but right now I simply cannot remember what I did!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
require('should');
```

to

```
import * as should from 'should';
```

Because I was porting this file from vanilla JS to TypeScript, I only changed some of the `require` statements, but not every one. Remember to change them all!